# Which HTTP protocol is used by Restlet 2.0?

Tags: http, restlet

I am using Restlet 2.0, I am wondering which http protocol is used? HTTP 1.1 or HTTP 1.0? How can I configure the protocol settings?

Thanks in advance!

Ikeforward

Comment: Just watch your network traffic using, for instance, Fiddler (www.fiddler2.com) and the protocol version will be plainly displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It supports HTTP 1.1 mainly. Some pluggable connectors for Restlet might be backward compatible with HTTP 1.0 though.